# Not able to download Zip File from a HTTP 302 Response using Java REST API

Tags: java, rest, file, http, curl

I am trying to access a Java REST API on Server A and I am trying to download a file from Server A. The HTTP Request for a File comes to Server A Java API and If it is missing from Server A I have to redirect it to Server B Java API for which I know the IP Address which is under same load balancer and redirect from Server A to Server B using the below code

```
String destinationUri = "https://serverB_IP/68629e2f-5157-4c0c-8ba8";
Response.ok().header("AuthToken", authToken).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://"+serverA_IP).header("Access-Control-Allow-Method", HttpMethod.GET).header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).status(302).location(destinationUri).build();
```

My requirement is to download the File from Server B to client location. When I run curl to REST API on Server A I get the following response when I enable verbose flag on the curl command.

```
curl -v -s -k -o test.zip -H "AuthToken: testToken" "https://serverA_IP/68629e2f-5157-4c0c-8ba8"
*   Trying 1xx.xx.xx.xxx:443...
* Connected to 1xx.xx.xx.xxx port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: using IP address, SNI is not supported by OS.
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /serverA_IP/68629e2f-5157-4c0c-8ba8 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 1xx.xx.xx.xxx
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> AuthToken: testToken
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2024 16:18:27 GMT
< Server: Acme
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains
< AuthToken: testToken
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://serverA_IP
< Access-Control-Allow-Method: GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: application/octet-stream
< Location: https://serverB_IP/68629e2f-5157-4c0c-8ba8
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:; frame-ancestors 'none'; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;
<
* Connection #0 to host 1xx.xx.xx.xxx left intact
```

I cannot download the file to client location from where curl command is ran and an empty test.zip is created.

Comment: Check the error code for 302 (i.e. "moved"), and if it exists, check the `Location` header in the response. In your case, you'd get `https://serverB_IP/68629e2f-5157-4c0c-8ba8`, the forwarded request location.

Comment: I am getting the Location URL in the curl response but my requirement is to trigger API on Server B and download the test.zip file. Can you please let know how to do that